# how to make logo centered and nav right aligned and then stacked on top for responsive

Tags: html, css, media

I'm having a problem getting the result by having the logo centered and then the nav right aligned and centered vertically within the header and then as it scales down to a responsive mode it will stack on top of one another. I can get the desired effect on the desktop mode by making the nav position: absolute; but then it screws up my responsive queries.

Anyone have an idea?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W37Wq/1/

HTML

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <a href="www.google.com"><img class="logo" src="http://www.techcityng.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/google.jpg"></a>
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Let's Partner</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <header class="clearfix">
```

CSS

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    z-index: 10000;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header .header-inner {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 69em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.875em;
    text-align: center;
}

.header h1,
.header nav a {
    line-height: 100px;
}

.header h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: block;
    block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 5em;
    position: absolute;
}

.header nav a {
    color: #aaa;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    font-size: .9em;
}

.header nav a:hover {
    color: #333;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 198px;
    max-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 55em) {

    .header .header-inner {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .header .logo,
    .header nav {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }

    .header .logo,
    .header nav a {
        line-height: 50px;
    }

    .header nav a {
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    .header .logo,
    .header.header-shrink nav a {
        line-height: 45px;
    }

    .header .logo {
        font-size: 2em;
        max-height: 60px;


    }

    .header.header-shrink nav a {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 32.25em) {
    .header nav a {
        font-size: .9em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 24em) {
    .header nav a,
    .header.header-shrink nav a {
        line-height: 1;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W37Wq/1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/W37Wq/4/

Chenge this class:

```
    .header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: #f6f6f6;
        z-index: 10000;
        height: 110px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .header .header-inner {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0% 5%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 55em) {

        .header .header-inner {

        }

        .header .logo,
        .header nav {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            float: none;
            width:90%;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:relative;` in your media query call:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 55em) {

    .header .logo,
    .header nav {
       display: block;
       margin: 0 auto;
       text-align: center;
       float: none;
       position:relative;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gGGLd

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did actually try that before but then was running into problems when it would revert back out of the media query. The other answer was the solution, thanks for helping though!

Comment: Glad you figured it out